# Can casting cause minute discrepancies in value?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm currently writing the Change Return Program on [The Big List of Projects](https://github.com/karan/Projects-Solutions) and I encountered a logic error in my code. Here is the snippet in question:

```
if(change / 1 >= 1) // checks if when divided the value is higher than 1, signaling that there is at least a dollar in change
{
    double temp1 = change % 1; // declared as double for casting
    temp1 = change - temp1; // and used to remove excess, non-dollar value
    dollarNum = (int) temp1;
    change -= (double)dollarNum;
}
```

Where change is a double that before this has a value of 10.01. However, after this snippet runs, the value becomes 0.00999999999999979, rather than 0.01 as I want it. Am I assuming something is wrong with casting here? Or is it something else entirely?

Also, note that I tried reformatting the last line to "change = change - `dollarNum` and tried swapping out `dollarNum` with `temp1` to avoid casting in that line, but neither fixed the issue.

If I formatted anything wrong please let me know and I'll surely fix it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double is not suitable for this kind of calculation because it does not store the value exactly (internally it uses binary fractions instead of decimal ones).

Use 'the 'decimal' type instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal):

```
        decimal change = 10.1M;
        if(change / 1 >= 1) //checks if when divided the value is higher than 1, signalling that there is at least a dollar in change
        {
            decimal temp1 = change % 1; //declared as double for casting
            temp1 = change - temp1; //and used to remove excess, non-dollar value
            int dollarNum = (int)temp1;
            change -= (decimal)dollarNum;
        }
```

Comment: `decimal` *also* doesn't store exact values, it just has a different set of values it can store exactly than `double`, and `.1` is a value that `decimal` can store exactly but `double` can't.

Comment: That's right, but since it uses decimal fractions internally, it can store 'human' monetary values (which are expressed in decimal)  exactly as long as their precision is smaller than that of 'decimal' type (about 28 significant digits). This is (almost) always the case when dealing with monetary values.